# How do you plot a bar graph for given values in a row rather than the number there are in the whole dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, seaborn

I just need a bar graph showing the `Name` along the x-axis, and for the bars to match up with their `Number` along the y-axis

```
series = pd.Series(np.arange(5))
df = pd.DataFrame(['Mel','James','Bob','Frank','Julia'], columns=['Name'])
df['Number'] = series

    Name    Number
0   Mel     5
1   James   6
2   Bob     7
3   Frank   8
4   Julia   9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the index

```
df.set_index('Name').plot.bar()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that was really bothering me.